# Any way to make options reactive for Array Objects fields using Meteor, AutoForm and SimpleSchema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

Please check the following image:
[image: AutoForm generated Array of Objects]

Right now we have this array of objects defined in the schema as follows:

```
`destinationCountry: {
    type: Array,
    label: () => {return TAPi18n.__('destinationCountry.label')},  
    minCount:1,
    maxCount:5,
},
'destinationCountry.$': {
    type: Object,
    label:()=>{ return " "},

},
'destinationCountry.$.country':{
    type:String,
    autoform:{ 
    type: "select2",
    'data-placeholder': () => {return TAPi18n.__('destinationCountry.placeholder')},
    options: () => {return TAPi18n.__('countryList', {returnObjectTrees:true, joinArrays:false})}, 
    afFieldInput: {
        multiple: false,
        width: 'resolve',

      },
      afQuickField: {
        'panelClass': 'col'
    },
}
},
'destinationCountry.$.days':{
    type:String,
    autoform:{
        type:"select",
        options:function (){
         // here is where the suggested code would go
        },

    }

},`
```

Now, is there any way to make it so that the options in days are reactive to the ones selected in the previous array index object for $.days? We would like so that if the maximum of days in all the $.days fields is 20, as soon as you select 13 in one of them, there will only be 7 available for all the other $.days select fields. How could we achieve this reactively?

update 1:

I tried the following:

```
'destinationCountry.$.days': {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
        type: "select",
        options: function () {
            let arr = [...Array(days.get())].map((v, i) => i);
            let finalArr = [{
                label: "Connection Flight",
                value: 0
            }]
            arr.map((v, i) => {
                finalArr.push({
                    label: (v + 1).toString(),
                    value: i + 1
                })
            });

            if (this.name == 'destinationCountry.0.days') {
                var usedDays = 0;
                var usedArr;
                if (AutoForm.getFormValues('step2') == null) {
                    usedArr = []
                    console.log("usedArr", usedArr)
                } else {
                    usedArr = AutoForm.getFormValues('step2').insertDoc.destinationCountry
                    console.log("usedArr", usedArr)
                }

                for (let index = 0; index < usedArr.length; index++) {
                    const element = Number(usedArr[index].days);
                    usedDays += element
                }
                console.log("finalArr", finalArr)
                if (usedDays == 0) {
                    console.log('usedDays', usedDays)
                    return finalArr
                } else if (usedDays > 0) {
                    newFinalArr = finalArr.slice(0, "-" + (usedDays));
                    return newFinalArr
                }
            }

            if (this.name == 'destinationCountry.1.days') {
                var usedDays = 0;
                var usedArr;
                if (AutoForm.getFormValues('step2') == null) {
                    usedArr = []
                    console.log("usedArr", usedArr)
                } else {
                    usedArr = AutoForm.getFormValues('step2').insertDoc.destinationCountry
                    console.log("usedArr", usedArr)
                }

                for (let index = 0; index < usedArr.length; index++) {
                    const element = Number(usedArr[index].days);
                    usedDays += element
                }
                console.log("finalArr", finalArr)
                if (usedDays == 0) {
                    console.log('usedDays', usedDays)
                    return finalArr
                } else if (usedDays > 0) {
                    newFinalArr = finalArr.slice(0, "-" + (usedDays));
                    return newFinalArr
                }
            }
        },

    }

},
```

[First days option array gets erased when adding the second array object...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSVT2.png)

Now every time you select an option in the first destinationCountry.0.days, the 1.days select gets correctly reduced depending on the number you select in the 0.days field. but it re-renders and removes the option selected in the first 0.days. is there any way to set and keep the value selected for the first 0.days field?

Comment: Use [AutoForm.getFormValues](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/master/api.md#autoformgetformvaluesformid-template-ss-getmodifierclient) in the `options` function and filter the array by the already selected form values. If you face errors, you can add them to this post.

Comment: @Jankapunkt could you please elaborate your suggestion a bit more? the options are to be generated in the `options` function, and right now all the instances of $.days are going to have the same options regardless of what we choose in any of the $.days dropdown.